# insert or update in realm cause duplication

Tags: android, realm

I'm new to realm android and I'm try to perform `bgRealm.insertOrUpdate(write_feed);` operation but I found out that the record is duplicated. after that I tried to to set primary key to my model which I use url(string and not autoincrement) as my primar key it cause all the insertion failed. how to set a unique key to my url so that insertOr Update works

Comment: Could you add stacktrace with error to your question?

Comment: 'FeedTable' has a primary key, use 'createObject(Class<E>, Object)' instead.

Comment: If you just need a random key you can use `@PrimaryKey private String id = UUID.random().toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in order to make `bgRealm.insertOrUpdate(write_feed);` works, we need to set a primarykey in my case is the url the reason why is the insertion failed is because of I din't specific my primarkey value during create object.

```
write_feed = new FeedTable(); // Create a new object
write_feed.setFeed(feedJSON);
write_feed.setUpdatedtime(System.currentTimeMillis());
bgRealm.insertOrUpdate(write_feed);
```